# Bootstrap 3 navigation bar logo placement in left sidfe with menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Need to create a reponsive template using Bootstrap v3 like the screenshot given below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKwgz.jpg

I tried it but something wrong. If anyone know, please give me the code

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself.  Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

look in the `navBar`

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="yourLogo.png" /></a>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2781/)

---

129px for logo height? easy!

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 129px; /*default was 50px*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<img src="logo.png" width="200" height="129" />
</a>
```

Feel free to tweak the code to your need!

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2961/)</kbd>

Comment: i tried like http://jsfiddle.net/yg8gg/9/.i need like http://i.imgur.com/40ZwNut.jpg

Comment: logo height should be 129px.i tried to add but. menus goes on top.i need logo and menu on same line.please check the demo image url above

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2961/ you have to tweak the css and HTML to get the desired output